# Find all $n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $n^2 + n + 1$ divide $n^3-22$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

I need help with this problem:

Find all $n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $n^2 + n + 1$ divide $n^3-22$.

I've got to a point where I know that $n^2 + n + 1 | -21$. So it should be among {${-21, -7, -3, -1, 1, 3, 7, 21}$}.

How could I continue? Thanks

Comment: That's only $8$ possibilities, why not check them all?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Isnt there a another way? It's only ok for a small amount of numbers... and besides those would be numbers that satisfy $n^2+n+1$. So I should also then find which of these are solutions to that equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for all eight of these numbers whether they satisfy the given property. The ones that do are your solution.